# if order is cancelled set price amount to zero

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My accountant asked me to be updating all WooCommerce cancelled order's amounts/prices with 0. This is the proper EU VAT way he said and I'm struggling to find a way to do that - I don't even have a starting point yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled', 'set_zero_amounts' );

function set_zero_amounts($order_id){
    // get an instance of an WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // get the ID of the order
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
}
```

Comment: Surely WooCommerce has a specific routine for cancelling/cancelled orders??

Comment: Your accountant should account only orders that have payment ?!?! Why would he care about cancelled orders ?

Comment: If you haven't received the payment for that order, you can set it to `cancelled` and such orders should not be accounted. If you have received the payment and the order had been accounted already, you should set the status to `refunded` and your accountant should issue a credit note for that order. Setting order totals to 0 manually is definitely a bad approach.